# Wrong computation result of numpy array in for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have the following code that computes a wrong number in python with numpy array claimed already:

```
for t in range(T-1,0,-1):
    dh[:,t,:] = dh[:,t,:] + dprev_ht
    dx[:,t,:], dprev_ht, dWxt, dWht, dbt = rnn_step_backward(dh[:,t,:], cache[t])
    dWx += dWxt
    dWh += dWht
    db += dbt
```

But if I change it to:

```
for t in range(T-1,0,-1):
    cur_dh = dh[:,t,:] + dprev_ht
    dx[:,t,:], dprev_ht, dWxt, dWht, dbt = rnn_step_backward(cur_dh, cache[t])
    dWx += dWxt
    dWh += dWht
    db += dbt
```

Then I can get the correct number. Is this problem related to the order or precedence of computation in python or the mutability of numpy array in for loop? Or am I totally wrong about this question?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hard to say without knowing what `rnn_step_backward` does, as well as how the loop is called.

Comment: Does `cache[t]` modify `t` or any other variable ?

Comment: Hi, `cache[t]` does not modify `t`.

Comment: Hi, regarding the `rnn_step_backward`, my code is the same as this one on github (https://github.com/Burton2000/CS231n-2017/blob/master/assignment3/cs231n/rnn_layers.py)